# SSH Security warning after trying to connect to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 2B which is always powered on. Recently I have been away for a couple of weeks and when I came back, I tried to SSH in to the device however both PuTTY and WinSCP gave me a

> WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH

error message.

I aborted the PuTTY connection however I continued with WinSCP, when I looked at the home folder everything that was there is still there.

I am not really sure what could have caused this. Could it be other computers on my network? This seems unlikely to me since all machines have ESET installed on them and I doubt that a Smart TV could do a man in the middle attack.

Comment: Was the Pi2B rebooted?  Perhaps it has been assigned a new IP address, which may cause the warning if you ssh by name.  You need to find a method of getting more detailed warnings.

Comment: I always SSH using the IP address, usually if it reboots and gets a new IP then PuTTY just gives me a "The server's host key is not cached in the registry" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a key from some other install cached in ~/.ssh/known_hosts for that IP, ssh will warn you. Just remove the old key to remove the warning. Putty uses the Windows Registry instead of a text file as it's the windows way.